# What species of bird is on this coin?

Tags: species-identification

What species of bird is depicted on this coin?

[image]

http://www.artic.edu/aic/collections/citi/images/standard/WebLarge/WebImg_000100/139651_846511.jpg

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: well I don't think this is really a biology question given that it is probably quite an "artistic" impression of the bird, but some clues as to the coins origin would help people hazard a best guess at most.

Comment: The coin shows Ptolomey I Soter I, a ruler of ancient Egypt c. 367 BC – c. 283 BC. [This Source](http://www.edgarlowen.com/greek-coins-egypt.shtml) suggests that it is an eagle standing on a thunderbolt.  This is corroborated [here](http://www.wildwinds.com/coins/sg/sg7761.html) and [again here](http://www.snible.org/coins/hn/egypt.html) so this seems most likely.  This question isn't really answerable from within our site scope, however, see the species identification tag wiki.  Hope the above helps though!

Answer (score 5):

[It said to be an eagle](http://www.wildwinds.com/coins/greece/egypt/ptolemy_V/i.html).

It looks like a Ptolemy V (204–181 BC):

http://www.bonanza.com/listings/-DD-G-068-Ptolomy-V-Octadrachm-COPY/16293418?gpid=21297750541&gpkwd=&goog_pla=1&gclid=CMWBpbOaxrUCFYx_Qgod6TsA9w

it looks to be a pretty standard motif of that era:

[image: Alexander III Great 336 BC Greek Coin]

From: http://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/alexander-iii-great-336bc-greek-coin-150614256

I agree that this is not really a biology question.. but what the hey.

Comment: this is why we need new answer notifications when writing comments!

Comment: I know a professional ichthyologist who once had to propose an identification for a fish painted on a cave wall. Surely it is more difficult than identifying from a real specimen, a photo or a scientific drawing, but in some case, artistic representations have a precise biological source of inspiration, and it is meaningful to try identifying it.
If we didn't already knew what species of bird is represented here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Seal_Of_The_President_Of_The_United_States_Of_America.svg
I think it would make sense trying a identification.